# Is there a way of getting xml data on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, xml-parsing

I am trying to get some simple json data into my site. I have tried various options with ajax and json but nothing seems to be giving me the results I need.

All I need is the data request and then on success it appends the results to a div. The url is a proper xml url but it seems to be giving me errors even when I do set it up.

Any ways without using plugins that people could recommend?

Cheers,
Mark

EDIT

Code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.granma.cu/ingles/granmai_ingl.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
            var url = $(this).find('url').text();
            $('<div class="items" id="link_'+id+'"></div>').html('<a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a>').appendTo('#cuban-news');
            $(this).find('desc').each(function(){
                var brief = $(this).find('brief').text();
                var long = $(this).find('long').text();
                $('<div class="brief"></div>').html(brief).appendTo('#link_'+id);
                $('<div class="long"></div>').html(long).appendTo('#link_'+id);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: What have you tried?  Where is your code? What specific problem are you having (i.e something more specific than "not giving me the results I need.")?

Comment: Valid xml is not valid html. Using html method as append to xml data will strips out invalid html tags.

Comment: edited the above code as to what i am trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $.get('data.xml',function(data){
    // parse the data
 });
```

or

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "record.xml", 
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml){
    parseXML(xml); 
},
error: function(response, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);}
   });
});

function parseXML(xml) {
   $(xml).find('record').each(function () {
      var entry = new Object();
      entry.order= $(this).find('itemDesc').text();
      parsedList.push(entry);
   }
   send();
 }
```

in the send function just append the text to the div

Comment: it should.. i use this or the .post() when i create an xml file in my c# behind code and i send it back to js.. it shouldn't be any different its still an xml file

Comment: coolio, I will try that. I had variations of the same thing but it kept throwing errors.

Comment: just a quick question would it be send($().append('<div></div>'););

Comment: if thats what u wanna do in your function.. basically its ('whateverthecontaineris').append( <'div'> </div> );